# Suggestion for re-use of slightly burned caramel sauce / Lokum

Tags: dough, caramel, caramelization

I was trying to make some Lokum, a turkish gelly sweet.
You put together a sugar sauce and a mix of cornstarch and water to do it.
I realized too late that the sugar sauce almost burned, and now the whole dough has a bitter/slightly burned taste.

Do you have any suggestion about how to re-use it?

Comment: That's tough.  Many imperfect desserts can be broken up and put over ice cream, but that's an exception.

Comment: Just throw it out and be done with it.